# Excel Formula "if" formula assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am currently trying to get the below formula:

```
=DATEDIF(D9,TODAY(),"y")
```

to display as blank if cell D9 has no data in it.

I tried the below formula:

```
=if(D9=””,””,(DATEDIF(D9,TODAY(),"y")))
```

However, it seems to have a glitch, as it needs to work with conditional formatting where if the above formula is equal to or greater than a number than cell `D37`, it pops up an error alert "stop" box.

Currently with the reworked formula it is populating the error message box only if cell `D9` is blank, however, if I put a date in `D9` that meets the conditional formatting, the error message will not populate. Additionally, the cell the above formula resides in will not calculate the years.

**Side question, the conditional formatting will only allow for me to select one cell to compare against. I need for it to compare against two cells. Is this doable?

Comment: But what is the question? The formula works in a cell, but conditional formatting needs to return true/false. What does D37 have to do with anything? Please elaborate. And on the side question, Yes. One way is to use `AND()`

Comment: D9= Date of birth
D37 & D39= age caps
So if "today" minus D9 is greater than or equal to the age placed in cells D37 or D39, say age 65, the conditional formatting will return the STOP box with my designated message.
However, I need for the error only to populate once cells D9, D37, and D39 have values placed in them.